# TabsPagerAdapter How to start with case 1 or another? - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-tabs

I have 12 page in tabspageradapter and I don't want to start with case 0. For example I want to start with case 4. How can I do that?

This is my adapter.

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new JanuaryFragment();
        case 1:
            return new FebFragment();
        case 2:
            return new MarchFragment();
        case 3:
            return new AprFragment();
        case 4:
            return new MayFragment();
        case 5:
            return new JuneFragment();
        case 6:
            return new JulyFragment();
        case 7:
            return  new AugustFragment();
        case 8:
            return  new SepFragment();
        case 9:
            return new OctFragment();
        case 10:
            return new NovFragment();
        case 11:
            return new DecFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 12;
}

}
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Try `yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(4);`

Comment: oh I tried to do that but It didn't work before. I tried once more when you said it, and it worked :)

Thanks for your answer.